# filtering SSRS expressions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression

I have a tablix which has an expression as a Row header and its shows Yr2018-Q1 expression below:

```
="Yr"&Fields!YEAR.Value & "_Q" & Fields!qtr.Value
```

I'm trying to show only as far back as Yr2017-Q2 for e.g

[image]

currently the tablix  show like below:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need a filter on your tablix, or need to include a `WHERE` in your dataset. Do you have actual date column in your dataset?

Comment: currently there is a filter 

=Fields!YEAR.Value*100+Fields!Qtr.Value <= =Parameters!Year.Value*100+Parameters!Qtr.Value

where parameters Year is set to 2018  as default value and Qtr has 1,2,3,4 as available values.

Comment: What about my other question about the date field?

Comment: yes the Yr and Qtr are the date fields in the dataset, but is it possible to handle it on the tablix filter ?

Comment: If it's a date, then simply filter choose the field in your filter, select `>=` as the operator, and `2017-04-01` for the value (as April 2017 is the start of Q2 in 2017).

Comment: yes but any other way around with expressions without actually hard-coding 201704, there is actually a yearmonth column that has yyyymm values. I'm trying something like yearmonth-13   (like 13 months back)

Answer (score 2):

As Larnu said the best way to do this is filter by a date column if you have it. However, this will only work if you have a way of mapping a quarter to a specific date. If that is not the case, the following should work for your filter expression:

**Expression**

```
Switch(Fields!YEAR.Value = Parameters!Year.Value
    And Fields!qtr.Value >= Parameters!Qtr.Value, 1,
    Fields!YEAR.Value > Parameters!Year.Value, 1,   
    1=1, 0
)
```

**Operator**

`=`

**Value**

`1`

There is no default case with a switch statement, hence the `1=1`, which always evaluates to `True`.